# Trying to increment a dynamic url

Tags: django

I have a dynamic URL that takes the id of a model in the address.

#urls

```
 url(r'^story/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.story, name='story')
```

Is there a way to make a link that increments the id?  So that in the template there would be an a href link that takes the current page lets say www.myapp.com/story/12 and the link increments the id by 1 so that the new address the link sends you to is www.myapp.com/story/13.

Comment: Can you add some more context...what are you trying to do ?

Comment: And what if you don't have a Story with ID 13?

Comment: Please show your story view.